# Button not displayed Android

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, android-button

I am having a linearlayout and scrollbar. I am trying to have button below the scrollbar.
Can you please suggest what I am doing wrong here.

Here is my XML code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>
 <Button             android:id="@+id/next_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Next"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"

            />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks,

Aman

Comment: your code is working for me Button displayed

Comment: i agree with @Sreekanthss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting `ScrollView` weight to 1 and height to 0dp it will wrap its height to fill all the space left after the `Button`gets layouted to use wrap_content height:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I added some description :)

Answer (score 0):

add

```
layout_weight
```

parameter to each part( i added 90% scrollview 10% button)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="9" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>
 <Button             android:id="@+id/next_btn"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Next"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use Relative layout in place of LinearLayout. That will solve some problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     >
<Button          

            android:id="@+id/next_btn"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Next"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"


            />
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_above="@id/next_btn" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/table_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```